# Cannot convert Data to NSDictionary

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to convert data from URLSession to a NSDictionary but it fails when converting the data to dictionary.

Following:

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
print(json ?? "NotWorking")
```

outputs

```
(
  {
    babyId = 1;
    id = 17;
    timestamp = "2018-06-30 09:23:27";
  }
)
```

But when I try to convert it into a Dictionary with following it outputs nil.

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary
```

The webpage outputs

```
[{"id":"17","babyId":"1","timestamp":"2018-06-30 09:23:27"}]
```

Where does the error occurs?

Comment: Convert it to an array, which contains the dictionaries that you want.

Comment: Don’t use NSDictionary or NSArray in Swift.

Comment: If you did `as! NSDictionary` you would have a crash and an error saying can't convert an Array into a Dictionary. Also, notice the `[ ]` on the JSON, or notice the `( )` for the print (which is in fact calling the `description` method of a NSArray). All this would tell you that your JSON is an Array at top level and not a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ ]` means array in JSON. `{ }` means dictionary. You have an array of dictionary. Note that when you print an array in Swift, you will see `( )`.

Don't use `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` in Swift without a very clearly understood and specific reason. Use a Swift array and dictionary of the proper types.

Your code should be:

```
do {
    if let results = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
        // results is now an array of dictionary, access what you need
    } else {
        print("JSON was not the expected array of dictonary")
    }
} catch {
    print("Can't process JSON: \(error)")
}
```

And really you shouldn't be using `data!` either. Somewhere above this you should have a `if let data = data {`